# If a morphism of vector bundles is a vector space isomorphism on the fibres, then it it a vector bundle isomorphism.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

The following is a definition of a vector bundle isomorphism.

> Let $E,F$ be vector bundles over a base manifold $M$. A smooth map $u:E\rightarrow F$ is a an isomorphism of vector bundles if
>
> 1. $u$ respects the fibres, that is for all $x\in M$ it follows that $u_x:=u|_{E_x}:E_x\rightarrow F_x$.
> 2. for each $x\in M$ the map $u_x$ is a vector space isomorphism.

It is not obvious to me how this implies that there is a smooth inverse $u^{-1}:F\rightarrow E$.It's clear that it has something to do with vector bundles being locally trivial but I am not sure how to complete my arguement.

Let $U$ be a neighborhood on which $E$ and $F$ are trivial. Then there are diffeomorphism $\phi:E_U\rightarrow U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi:F_U\rightarrow U\times \mathbb{R}^n$. but since clearly $U\times \mathbb{R}^n \cong U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ it follows that $E_U \cong F_U$. So we have shown that $E$ and $F$ as manifolds are locally diffeomorphic?

I'm not sure if this is correct, and I haven't shown that $u$ has a smooth inverse.

Comment: Define the inverse map by gluing together all the $u_x^{-1}$ into a single map $F \to E$. Local triviality kicks in when one shows that this inverse is indeed smooth. With respect to local trivializations, one can represent it by a matrix, and the operation of inverting a matrix is rational in its entries (hence smooth).

Comment: This is basically just the inverse function theorem. You can see that $u$ is a bijection, so we only need to show $u^{-1}$ is smooth. Locally this is true because, passing to coordinates, $u$ is locally invertible at each point, and by the same theorem the local inverse is smooth.

Comment: @ElliotG if it is enough to show smoothness locally, does that mean my argument works? shouldn't we have show that it is smooth on overlaps as well? I'm not entirely comfortable with how to justify if a map is locally smooth it must be smooth

Comment: Almost, but you should write it differently. You aren't trying to show that $E_U$ and $F_U$ are diffeomorphic, but rather that $u$ *is* such a diffeomorphism

Comment: I think I understand, could you expand on how going to local coordinates does this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing map is vector bundle isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458781/showing-map-is-vector-bundle-isomorphism)

Comment: @PaulFrost almost, I just unsure about why showing this locally is good enough? Perhaps I should but this comment on that question. If we show it is smooth on a small open neighborhood, how do we get that this smoothness agress on the overlaps of two small neighborhoods. I know that the overlap of the two small neighborhoods will also be a neighborhood our map is smooth on but something just isn't clicking or i feel like im missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially the same as [Showing map is vector bundle isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458781). The difference is that you work in the smooth category.

$GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is smooth submanifold of $End(\mathbb R^n) \approx \mathbb R^{n^2}$ and it is well-known that for product bundles the assignment $\phi \mapsto \phi''$ given in my answer to the linked question establishes a bijection between smooth bundle maps $\phi$ ansd smooth maps $\phi'' : B \to GL(n,\mathbb R)$ (provided $B$ is a smooth manifold).

Since inversion in $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is smooth, we see that $\phi^{-1}$ is smooth.

This transfers to smooth bundle maps between trivial bundles.

Thus, if $u :  E \to F$ is a general smooth bundle map, we see that $u^{-1} : F \to E$ is locally smooth. But local smoothness implies global smoothness. This follows from the definition of a smooth map - it is a local property. You can also find it in any good textbook.